If I marry a Japanese Woman will I go straight to hell?
I'm a Kshatriya by Varna just in case that's needed to be known.
Do scriptures allow Hindus to marry foreigners?
In this question the answer seems to outright suggest that it's a huge sin to marry a Mleccha. but then i did some digging and found out that Mleccha doesn't mean that if someone is of a Foreign nation they're automatically a Mleccha, as the term Mleccha can even be applied to a Brahmin who does sinful acts and degrades himself to a Mlecchas level.
Since Mleccha seems to be about the Gunas of the person and not the "Race" of the person.
If I marry a Japanese woman who has good qualities such as, Vedic Dharma following, Vegetarian, good behaviour etc.
Will It still be sinful? For marrying a woman outside of my Varna and will I get punished for this in hell?

It means that all foreigners all mlecchas, but some non-foreigners(Aryas)are non-noble, i.e. non-aryan and therefore mlecchas

It would be a pāpa for an ārya to have vivāha with a mleccha, even if that mleccha is satyavādī, udāra, an āstika Hindu, who does devapūjana, etc. Here, mleccha is specifically being used for those who belong to mlecchadeśas, and those who don’t belong to any of caturvarṇas and miśrajātis.

Yes, that is true. In Bhagavad Gita Chapter 18 it has been mentioned that one's caste is as per their guns, born of their own nature. Same thing has been mentioned in Bhagavata Purana Part 7 Chapter 11. Irrespective of religion or beliefs, good deeds and good behaviour is everyone's duty.

Okay so caste is based on individual person's guna yes? So it would not be a sin for me to marry a foreign woman who has good Gunas?
